# Form Posts Text Inputs But Not File

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, post

I am trying to submit file inside a form to Laravel backend. It posts all the other text fields but not file (when I `dd($request->all())`)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <input id="item_price" type="item_price" class="form-control" name="item_price" value="">
    <!-- other inputs -->

    <input type="file" id="product_image" name="product_image" onchange="previewImage(this);"/>
    <img id="previewing" src="{{asset('noImage.gif')}}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" /> 
</form>
```

`item_price` seems on `dd($request->all())` and also other fields are seen, but no file input

When I display the image with jQuery (`previewImage`) before submitting the form, it shows the photo. But after I submit the form, on Laravel side it shows all the other fields and values but not any for file (when I use `dd($request->all())`.

On `php.ini`, `max-post-size` is 100M.

```
   jQuery('#previewing').click(function() {
        uploadImageClicked();
   });

   function uploadImageClicked() {
        jQuery('#product_image').click();
   }
```

`dd($request->hasFile('product_image')` returns false

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel (which should be tagged in your question) it's not part of the `Request` class with the other form values, it's in the `file` method.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

`$file = $request->file("image");` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Both `dd($request->file("image"));` and `dd($request->file("image"));` returns null. Also `dd($request->image);` is null

Comment: The name of your `file input` is `image` .. what does `dd($request->hasFile('image'))` return? If the input name is actually "image" then that code snippet would work.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake on snippet. Let's say it images. `dd($request->hasFile('image'));` returns false now.. Still doesn't work

Comment: Update your question with the **actual** code of your form.

Comment: I updated to my original code. `dd($request->hasFile('product_image'))` => false. The name is `product_image` in name of input. `dd($request->all());`

Comment: The javascript for `previewImage()` may shed light if the input is being replaced or something as well. Please include all code in question. Do you have any other inputs already named `product_image`?

Comment: I added the javascript code in question. There is no any other inputs with product_image name. *Edited my question